# Nvidia gtx 1060 not booting and freezes on ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, nvidia

I have got a problem after upgrading my graphics card: Ubuntu freezes on startup.

I reinstalled Ubuntu from 16.04 live cd using nomodeset and acpi=off, and then I tried to use the system normally, installing latest Nvidia drivers (nvidia-370, v370.28 currently), but freezing still happen.
The freeze starts on ubuntu loading screen, with the dot animation. At some point it freezes, then reboot and black screen (and keyboard caps & bloqnum lights party).

I managed after a couple hours to boot, via Ubuntu advanced boot>Fail safe boot on grub, then pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, then Ctrl+C, and it starts normally.

I tried older and newer drivers, nouveau and so, but it didn't work.

Here you have the Xorg.failsafe.log: http://pastebin.com/UdBQR4Pr

The lspci: http://pastebin.com/qSbviUn1

And the dmesg: http://pastebin.com/SSpTPBXn

Thank you very much.

UPDATE (12/02/2017):

Still not working with NVIDIA drivers 378.09 and ubuntu 16.10, fresh install, same errors.

UPDATE 2 (26/02/2017):

Disbled secure boot and still doesn't work, but found that [adding nomodeset option to grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) do the workaround and let it boot "normally".

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

```
nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Nvidia driver does not load.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) for explanation.

Comment: The answer of Pilot6 is correct since you have an EFI motherboard which support secure boot by default. If you switch off `secure boot` you can load the driver and your security will NOT be diluted.

Comment: Secure boot disabled and still not working. I tried with nomodeset and surprisingly boot working: [adding nomodeset to grub options](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu). I update main answer with this workaround, but I think there should be a better solution.